# Docker-compose file with multiple database containers in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have a Laravel project with two mysql database containers. During seeding we're fetching data from database one and mapping/importing this into database two.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: aas
      MYSQL_USER: aas_admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

  access_db:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: access_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: access_aas
      MYSQL_USER: aas_admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - accessdbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/accessmy.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Redis
  cache:
    image: redis:rc-alpine3.11
    container_name: cache
    ports:
      - "6382:6379"
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
  accessdbdata:
    driver: local
```

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=aas
DB_USERNAME=aas_admin
DB_PASSWORD=secret

ACCESS_DB_CONNECTION=access
ACCESS_DB_HOST=access_db
ACCESS_DB_PORT=3307
ACCESS_DB_DATABASE=access_aas
```

I can access the database through SequelPro using the above credentials for both databases. I can also create migrations but seeding seems to be a problem when I query data from the `access_db`

When I try seed the database I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Please share the error message in text form, along with your debugging attempts

Comment: [Why you should not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: The image isn't code but rather console output and the problem is already solved. See below.

Comment: Yes, I saw it was solved.  I was suggesting you be a good SO citizen and make your question useful for future visitors (the link also describes this). Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in the .env file I needed to change:

**.env**

```
ACCESS_DB_PORT=3307 => ACCESS_DB_PORT=3306
```

I believe the reason for this is that Laravel is looking for a container inside the host in which case port 3307 doesn't exist.